# Sort observations from csv file by month to plot in R

Tags: r, csv

[This](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/stormevents/csv?sort=DT&statefips=37%2CNORTH%20CAROLINA&county=ALL&eventType=%28C%29%20Flash%20Flood&eventType=%28Z%29%20Flood&beginDate_yyyy=1996&beginDate_mm=01&beginDate_dd=01&endDate_yyyy=2014&endDate_mm=12&endDate_dd=31) link contains a csv file of a list of flood observations. I want to sort observations by month, so that I can make a histogram/bar chart of flood events by month in R. Here's what I can come up with:

```
f <- read.csv("storm_data_search_results.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
forder <- f[order(as.Date(f$BEGIN_DATE, format="%m")),]
hist(forder$BEGIN_DATE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conversion of date is incorrect. If you look at:

```
f$BEGIN_DATE[1:3]
#[1] "01/18/1996" "01/18/1996" "01/18/1996"
```

You should choose format `%m/%d/%Y` (see `?strptime` for format). And, if you want to extract month information, use `strptime()` instead of `as.Date()`.

```
## date conversion
f$BEGIN_DATE <- strptime(f$BEGIN_DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
## get month
f$month <- f$BEGIN_DATE$mon + 1L  ## 1L means integer 1
```

`month` takes values 1, 2, ..., 12. Then we can reorder `f` by `month`

```
forder <- f[order(f$month), ]
```

However, your question itself is very unclear. You said you want to draw a histogram per month, but I did not see any available data to produce such histogram. Your provided code:

```
hist(forder$BEGIN_DATE)
```

does not seem to make any sense to me. I think you mean:

```
hist(forder$month)
```

But what does this histogram mean? You can draw such histogram without reordering your data frame.

Anyway, I think your major problem has been solved. Now, the dataset is yours; you should find your way to get the histogram you want.

Comment: Thanks @Zheyuan, I was pretty much trying to develop a histogram to see the frequency of events per month, which required me to categorize the events by their respective month. I just had an incomplete format.